# How to remove grub

Tags: grub2, boot-loader

I want to remove grub from one of my disks to make sure I don't accidently boot from it. But I want to remove only the boot loader, the data needs to stay intact.

Edit: I of course don't want to remove Linux, only clear a bootloader from the previously primary disk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create backup of first 446b on your disk (this is not all MBR - it has 512b), so when your disk is `/dev/sda`:

```
:~# dd if=/dev/sda of=/data/disk.img bs=446 count=1
```

And next remove (only erase bootloader without disk table):

```
:~# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=446 count=1
```

If you revert:

```
:~# dd if=/data/disk.img of=/dev/sda bs=446 count=1
```

Comment: Note: since Windows 2000, Microsoft uses octets 441-446 for a 32-bit disk signature followed by 2 octets of zeroes. So, it might be better to still backup the full 446 octets, but only overwrite the first 440. Actually, it would probably be enough to just overwrite the first octet, after all, all you need to achieve is that the boot loader code is no longer valid x86 machine code.

Comment: Thanks, I did as @JörgWMittag proposed and overwrote only the first 440b, but it worked as expected.

Comment: What if we are in a GPT world?