# Remove GRUB on a GPT disk

Tags: partition, grub2, gpt

I have a HDD that which has GPT that was created for a BIOS motherboard (not UEFI!) This drive used to house my Debian installation. Since I bought an SSD and a new UEFI motherboard, now I would like to use this HDD as only storage (no boot from it)

I will delete my `root`, `/home` and `swap` partitions. But the remaining partitions on it that has data that I would like to keep. So I can't just create a new GPT and lose all my data.

How can I remove GRUB without nuking the entire disk?

**PS**: here is how the HDD looks currently:

```
$ sudo gdisk /dev/sdc
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.8

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.

Command (? for help): p
Disk /dev/sdc: 1953525168 sectors, 931.5 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 2758BB06-C7E7-451B-9C92-F1B278721BB6
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 1953525134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 3437 sectors (1.7 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048            6143   2.0 MiB     EF02  
   2            6144         8394751   4.0 GiB     8200  
   3         8394752        76754943   32.6 GiB    8300
   4        76754944       174409727   46.6 GiB    0700  
   5       174409728      1346283519   558.8 GiB   0700  
   6      1346283520      1953523711   289.6 GiB   0700
```

and what partition is what:

```
$ sudo lsblk -f
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL           MOUNTPOINT         
sdc                           
├─sdc1                        
├─sdc2 swap                   [SWAP]
├─sdc3 ext4                   /
├─sdc4 ext4                   /home
├─sdc5 ext4   store1          
└─sdc6 ntfs   store2
```

**PPS**: Would this command delete GRUB on **my** HDD?:

```
:~# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=446 count=1
```

(found this from another [topic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/319678/how-to-remove-grub))

Comment: Also, will it delete or alter the partition table?

Answer (score 1):

The `dd` command will delete GRUB from the Master Boot Record. The MBR only contains `boot.img` or "Stage 1" of GRUB. Stage 1.5 resides on the BIOS Boot Partition, which in your case is the 2.0 MiB partition with code `EF02`. (On a non-GPT disk, Stage 1.5 is stored in the gap between the MBR and the first partition, but with GPT there is no such gap.) You can delete this partition -- or just leave it there, it does no harm.