# Does erasing the MBR will touch the partition table?

Tags: hard-disk, gpt, mbr, partition-table

If I run this `dd` command to blank the first bytes of a MBR, will it have an effect on the current partition table of this disk (or just on grub)? Will the partitions still be recognized?

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=440 count=1
```

(440 is the result of an advice, and seems better than 446, see links below)

Because this command is meant to "Remove Grub from my disk", "Purge the MBR, so that the bios can't boot on it" or "Delete Stage 1 data".

References:

- [How to remove grub](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/319678/how-to-remove-grub)
- [Remove GRUB on a GPT disk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336262/remove-grub-on-a-gpt-disk)

Comment: Is your partition table GPT or MBR?

Comment: last 64 bytes contains the partition table, so should preserve partition table. First 440 bytes are assembly instructions for booting, and yeah you need to consider GPT and MBR like @roaima mentioned.

Comment: @Sagar want to write the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this command will make the disk unbootable in legacy BIOS style, but a MBR-style partition table will still be intact.

If the disk contains a FAT32 partition that contains a file named `\EFI\BOOT\BOOTx64.efi`, the disk may still be considered bootable in UEFI style. But if you want to make the disk unbootable in UEFI style, just rename or remove that file.

As you can see in the tables in [Wikipedia's description of the Master Boot Record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record), the partition entries are located starting from byte 446 onwards (0x01be in hexadecimal).

Your command will only overwrite the first 440 bytes (i.e. bytes 0 ... 439), also leaving the disk signature and copy protection indicator untouched.

Answer (score 0):

Erasing the first 440 bytes( only erases the boot code (assembly instruction that usually helps with first stage boot loader), provided the last 2 bytes of MBR are marked with signature 0xaa55. (510th and 511th byte, little endian: high byte is read first).

Next 6 bytes were kept reserved, they were used for disk signatures. Followed by that 64 bytes are used for partition table. So this should preserve your partition table. 
Like @telcoM mentioned in his answer, dd command only erases the first 440 bytes.

Be noted this is applicable for MBR scheme. The GPT divides disk into set of partitions and partition table is stored in separate partition (EFI system partition).

Comment: The primary GPT header starts on the next 512-byte block. The EFI System Partition is just a partition used to boot.